# add metrotabitem to metrotabcontrol

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, mahapps.metro

I created a usercontrol which is a tabitem with a close button.

when I add user control in wpf in any form as :

```
<UserControls:ClosableTab HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          Header="Check">
</UserControls:ClosableTab>
```

It works fine.it shows on screen and closes on close button.

But when I add this progamatically on any button click as :

```
ClosableTab t = new ClosableTab();
metroAnimatedTabControl.Items.Insert(metroAnimatedTabControl.Items.Count, t);
t.IsSelected = true;
```

though it shows up on screen but when I try to close it,below exception occurs:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>
> Additional information: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Could any one help me out with this>i have tried many things but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `MahApps.Metro` [1.0.0 is out](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MahApps.Metro), this should never happen anymore if you inherit from `MetroTabItem`.

```
public class ClosableTab : MetroTabItem
{
}
```

You can create your `TabItem` with or without giving the owner tab control.

So this should work without any issues:

```
ClosableTab t = new ClosableTab();
metroAnimatedTabControl.Items.Insert(metroAnimatedTabControl.Items.Count, t);
t.IsSelected = true;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, my ClosableTab is inheriting from MetroTabItem as mentioned by you but mahapps version I was using was 0.14.0,now I have installed  version 1.0.0 and its working fine now! Its ironic that I am facing this issue from last 2 days the same day version 1.0.0 was released! Thanks @punker76 aka Jan Karger!